assemblyAI and getting transcript function
here is my function that gets transcript from a local audio file
def get_transcript(link):
try:
audio_file = download_audio(link)
print(f"Downloaded audio file: {audio_file}")  # Debugging line
    aai.settings.api_key = "MY_API_KEY"
    transcriber = aai.Transcriber()
    transcript = transcriber.transcribe(audio_file)
    if transcript.text:
        print(f"Transcription: {transcript.text}")
    else:
        print(f"Transcription is empty")  # Debugging line
        print(transcript.error)
        return None

except Exception as e:
    print (f"Error getting transcript: {e}")
    return None

I have confirmed that the audiofile is not empty but I still keep getting transcription is empty, no transcription error, I don't see where I am making a mistake yet and MY_API_KEY is correct. print(f"Downloaded audio file: {audio_file}") works
I have tried adding print statements to my code, to see where it deviates from what is intended but I still do not understand why transcription keeps coming back empty if there is actually an audio file that plays for 0.12minutes

If I understood it correctly, your audio is ~7 seconds long. If you're not receiving any errors, it may be that you audio doesn't contain enough data to create a transcript.
Try a different audio file that's longer, to see whether that works.
